# with-open-file explanation in layman terms

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm learning CL, and I have minimal experience in other languages. Could someone explain to me in layman terms what this means, especially what "out" here represents, and how it all fits together:

```
(defun save-db (filename)
  (with-open-file (out filename
                   :direction :output
                   :if-exists :supersede)
    (with-standard-io-syntax
      (print *db* out))))
```

Mostly, the bit I don't understand is "out", but an explanation of the whole thing would be nice.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

out is the stream variable bound to the open file.
with-open-file guarantees that the file is open inside the scope, and closed
outside the scope, no matter how you exit.

Comment: How can I get manpages describing such things on Linux for CL please?

Comment: Manpages are a Unix tradition, and Lisp comes from a very distinct culture.  In general, I google "hyperspec" + (whatever term I'm curious about).

Comment: Or, in many cases you can use Lisp's built-in doc system: `(documentation 'foo 'function)` will look up documentation for the function or macro `foo`. Sadly, this seems to be missing in SBCL for the specific case of `with-open-file`.

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to ddyer, you can also use `MACROEXPAND` or `MACROEXPAND-1` to see what `WITH-OPEN-FILE` does:

```
(macroexpand '(with-open-file (out filename
                               :direction :output
                               :if-exists :supersede)
               (with-standard-io-syntax
                 (print *db* out))))
```

tells us

```
(LET ((OUT (OPEN FILENAME :DIRECTION :OUTPUT :IF-EXISTS :SUPERSEDE)) (#:G748 T))
  (UNWIND-PROTECT
      (MULTIPLE-VALUE-PROG1 (PROGN (WITH-STANDARD-IO-SYNTAX (PRINT *DB* OUT)))
        (SETQ #:G748 NIL))
    (WHEN OUT (CLOSE OUT :ABORT #:G748))))
```

We can see that we open the file called `filename` and assign that open file stream to `out` , and do something. Should something bad happen, `UNWIND-PROTECT` will `CLOSE` the stream, should it be non-`nil`.

The `#:G748` variable is a `GENSYM`ed symbol (so it's a fresh, uninterned, symbol). If nothing goes wrong writing the file, we set `#:G748` to `nil`.

Thus, when we `CLOSE` the stream, if something went wrong `#:G748` will be `T`, so `CLOSE` will attempt to clean up any side effects of having created the stream.